# your screenshots still do not sufficiently reflect your app in use

Tags: ios, iphone, screenshot

he tratado de publicar una app en appstore pero me siguen mandando esto:

> We noticed that your screenshots still do not sufficiently reflect
>   your app in use.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your screenshots to ensure that
>   they accurately reflect the app in use. For resources on creating
>   great screenshots for the App Store, you may want to review the App
>   Store Product
>   Pagehttps://developer.apple.com/app-store/product-page/ information
>   available on the Apple developer portal.
>
> Please ensure you have made any screenshot modifications using Media
>   Manager. You should confirm your app looks and behaves identically in
>   all languages and on all supported devices. Learn how to use Media
>   Managerhttp://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devd1093d90d
>   to add custom screenshots for each display size and localization.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola me volvieron a rechazar mis capturas                                               
 The screenshots that are currently displayed in your metadata do not reflect the current UI.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje esta bastante claro, me imagino solo estas mandando los tres screenshots que te piden como mínimo, pero estos deben de ser muy parecidos y no están mostrando todo el potencial y contenido de tu app.

Puedo entender que hay pantallas que no puedes mostrar por fines de uso, privacidad o lo que sea, o quizá tu app es simple y no cuenta con muchas pantallas.

Cual sea el caso mis recomendaciones son las siguientes:

1.- Si tienes mas pantallas, donde muestras información, datos personales o algo parecido, intenta modificar esta captura con datos "mockup", datos prototipo que no tengan significado para nadie, me explico?

2.- Mejora tus capturas, a Apple le gusta que el contenido sea atractivo a la vista, entonces trata de convertir lo simple a lo complejo, ejemplo, puedes utilizar alguna herramienta que te genera screenshots bastante atractivos como [Screenshot Builder](https://apptoolkit.io/screenshots/) (Hay muchas mas, o si puedes crear screenshots mas elaborados, quizá mostrando un iPhone prototipo o algo así, que mejor)

3.- A pesar de que [Apple pide que los screenshots sean de un dispositivo real](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html) y no el simulador, las apps con screenshots de simulador aun así son aceptadas, principalmente si no tienes un dispositivo en especifico para probarlo. Si estas ajustando tamaños para los tamaños de screenshots, no hagas eso, mejor utiliza el simulador.

4.- En apps de pago esta comprobado que la revisión de apple, especialmente para los screenshots es mucho mas minuciosa, Apple es el vendedor del producto ante el cliente, por tanto el responsable de las compras cuando los clientes están insatisfechos, es por ello que los screenshots deben de funcionar como un ejemplo claro y conciso de lo que contiene y la funcionalidad de tu aplicación.

Aveces durante el proceso de publicación nos pueden agarrar las prisas, pero esta es la parte mas importante del desarrollo de la app. Debe tomarse con calma y paciencia para hacerlo bien.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte, saludos!